# Bad Sector (250kb) (320GB SATA) how to map out bad sectors?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I've read that selecting the option (Full) Format will map the bad sectors but i am not sure what excatly a format on a HDD does because i have never tried that on a HDD only on USBs. Will it delete all the Opearting System (Windows 10)? Not that it's important to me because i have no important data on the disk but will i have to re-install the opearting system?

Another thing i've heard is partitioning the areas where the bad sectors are located that way the head won't read those areas and it would only read the healthy areas, but i have no idea how to do that. Anyone help me and give me a detailed explanation step by step on this?

Also i've tried running CHKDSK /R and it has scanned the drive but the Operating System still continues to have problems like loading interfaces or accessing a folder or at start up it takes long to load up or to shut down it takes minutes to shut down the drive.

I am going to try formatting it. Hope that helps. But i also want to try partitioning it. Also just let you know i am doing this just to see if i can revive the HDD. I already have 2 spare healthy HDD's that can i use. I am doing this just for experimenting. Perhaps i won't have to dispose of it and i can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the full drive or a partition. If you have bad sectors, and you want to format the whole drive, you cannot do that if there's an operating system on it from within that OS. You'll have to boot from another media and format the drive, then reinstall the OS.

But fist of all, get HD Tune and run a full scan to see if you indeed have unreadable sectors. Also, look at the S.M.A.R.T. values in the same program.